# error when php script call batch file

Tags: php, batch-file

I have file php script `run.php`:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$typeTest = $argv[1];    
`aaa.bat $typeTest`;    
?>
```

And batch file `aaa.bat`

```
@echo off
set a=%1
echo %a%
```

But, when run `php run.php string_here` on command line windows then error

```
'∩╗┐@echo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which editor you are using but it appears to be entering invalid characters at the start of the file. Some people say changing the encoding of the file works however that last time i had this issue it didn't work for me. I would recommend downloading notepad++ (its free) and then editing the file and re-saving with that program.

Edit: I tend to use ANSI for my encoding (since its the default selected in notepad anyway) without any issues. Given the size of your file you could just retype it in notepad and save with ANSI (Do not open in notepad and re-save as it may not show the byte mark for you to delete it)

Comment: That will be a UTF-8 BOM. Changing the encoding of the file will work, it is the solution, and it is what using Notepad++ would do - and even that would only work if you set the encoding right in Notepad++. He needs to change it to ISO-8859-1 or possibly UTF-8 without BOM